# Installing Bulbs on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, bulbs

I am trying to install bulbs on my system (Ubuntu 12.04). I came across this link. (http://bulbflow.com/download/#get-bulbs)

I am not using a Flask or any other virtual environment. I just want to install bulbs straight on my PC.

Is a:

```
$ pip install bulbs
```

do that for me?

sudo pip install https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/tarball/master

```
Downloading/unpacking https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/tarball/master
  Downloading master (unknown size): 177Kb downloaded
  Cannot determine compression type for file /tmp/pip-EuJ05B-unpack/master
  In the tar file /tmp/pip-EuJ05B-unpack/master the member espeed-bulbs-71d0cce/docs/social is invalid: "linkname 'espeed-bulbs-71d0cce/docs//home/james/projects/bulbflow.com/www/root/templates/social.html' not found"
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/tarball/master

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found under directory '.'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory '.'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*/*/old'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*/old'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bulbs==0.3.29-20140426)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2>=0.7.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bulbs==0.3.29-20140426)
Downloading/unpacking pyyaml>=3.10 (from bulbs==0.3.29-20140426)
  Downloading PyYAML-3.11.tar.gz (248Kb): 248Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyyaml

Downloading/unpacking six (from bulbs==0.3.29-20140426)
  Downloading six-1.6.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package six

    no previously-included directories found matching 'documentation/_build'
Downloading/unpacking omnijson (from bulbs==0.3.29-20140426)
  Downloading omnijson-0.1.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package omnijson

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil==1.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from bulbs==0.3.29-20140426)
Installing collected packages: pyyaml, six, omnijson, bulbs
  Running setup.py install for pyyaml
    checking if libyaml is compilable
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.o
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c:2:18: fatal error: yaml.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.

    libyaml is not found or a compiler error: forcing --without-libyaml
    (if libyaml is installed correctly, you may need to
     specify the option --include-dirs or uncomment and
     modify the parameter include_dirs in setup.cfg)

  Running setup.py install for six

    no previously-included directories found matching 'documentation/_build'
  Running setup.py install for omnijson

  Running setup.py install for bulbs

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found under directory '.'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory '.'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*/*/old'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*/old'
Successfully installed pyyaml six omnijson bulbs
Cleaning up...
```

It doesn't seem that pip is not doing a good job of installing all the dependanceis for bulbs.It couldn't find libyaml and I got a fatal error.

Comment: `virtualenv` is very strongly recommended for Python projects, but it's not an absolute requirement. The rest of the guide does say to install it with `pip install bulbs`, and then the rest of the steps.

Comment: Also Flask is a web application framework not a virtual environment, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using virtualenv, then you will more than likely need to run "sudo pip install bulbs" to install it onto your machine.  The default python installation is protected by root access on Ubuntu.  Also, you should not have to worry about other software to install, because  pip install will take care of dependencies if the "bulbs" package is formed correctly.

Comment: I didn't know that pip managed package dependancies as well.that is very handy!

Comment: Looks like pip is not doing a very good job of managing the depencencies? Why would that be?

Comment: It says "Successfully installed pyyaml six omnijson bulbs" -- pip worked, you're good and should be ready to go.